# What material is the Merlin 1D made from?

Tags: spacex, materials, merlin-1d

I am working on high school presentation about rocket engine materials and I'd like to have a part about Merlin 1D engine as it is supposed to be reusable, but I can't find anything about materials used for this kind of engine. Found a lot of data about single-use engines and solid rockets, but nothing about materials for reusable one.
Could you please provide anything about materials used? I have literally nothing to take off from...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: SpaceX publishes very little detail on their designs. You may have better luck using the Shuttle main engine (RS-25 or SSME) as an example, this was also designed to be reusable.

Answer (score 2):

The only information I have been able to find only gives what one part of the engine is made of. That is the merlin vacuum variant bell extension.

From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merlin_%28rocket_engine_family%29)

> Its combustion chamber is regeneratively cooled, while the 2.7 metres (9 ft)-long niobium alloy expansion nozzle is radiatively cooled.

Specifically, it uses niobium alloy c103 (89-90 Nb, 9-10 Hf, 1Ti), per http://www.alkane.com.au/images/pdf/asx/2017/20170516.pdf.

This backs up Hobbes comment that a lot of this information simply is not public.